# How sent verification email in parse upon resetting the current user of new email in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to sent verification link to email id after logged in by the current user in parse

Comment: As per my guess `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setEmail("test@email.com")` will send a verification email to `test@email.com`. You've to handle it as per your requirement when setting it.

Comment: no that will work only for signup, I am trying for after login in as cuurent user.

Comment: after a successful login, you can send an email using `Mandrill` in `Parse Cloud Code`. Currently I'm using it for sending feedback emails. Check more at https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mandrill
If you still need anything let me know.

Comment: My requirement is like how could i do same function using android or java.

Comment: Is it I need to work on server code?

Comment: if you put it in `Parse Cloud` then you can call same function/code from `Android`, `iOS` and `WP`. Still `Mandrill` has wrapper APIs http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738166-API-Wrappers. I recommend you use `Parse Cloud`.